# Move lines with tildes to a certain section of a file

Tags: filetype-markdown, plugin-vimwiki

I use vim to write my to-do list in markdown format.
To mark a certain task "done" I just make it strikethrough with two tildes(~).

Is there a way to automatically move all strikethrough text to a different section(#Things done, for example)?

And also is there a way to add a date to each task done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Moving completed tasks

Presuming that a done line looks like this:

```
- ~A completed task~
```

Then you can do so with a [`:global`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Ag) command that performs a [`:move`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Am):

```
:g/^- \~.*\~$/m/^# Things done/+1
:g                                  # find lines that match
  /^- \~.*\~$/                      # the regular expression /^- \~.*\~$/
              m                     # and move them below
                               +1   # one line below
               /^# Things done/     # the line that matches /# Things done/
```

The regular expression:

```
/^- \~.*\~$/
 ^            # the start of the line
  -           # a markdown list item
    \~        # a tilde
      .*      # anything
        \~    # another tilde
          $   # the end of the line
```

You're probably not going to want to type this out every time, so why not make it into a mapping:

```
:nnoremap <leader>c :g/^- \~.*\~$/m/^# Things done/+1<CR>
```

Now you can move completed items just by pressing <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>.

### Appending the time

You can use a similar command to append the current date:

```
:g/^- \~.*\~$/call setline('.', getline('.') . ' ' . strftime('%x'))
```

This works very similarly, but instead of moving the lines, it appends the current date to them. (See [`:help strftime`](http://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#strftime%28%29), [`:help getline`](http://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getline%28%29), and [`:help setline`](http://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#setline%28%29).)

### Doing both at once

If you don't want two separate mappings, you can wrap them in a function:

```
function CompleteTasks() abort
  g/^- \~.*\~$/m/^# Things done/+1
  g/^- \~.*\~$/call setline('.', getline('.') . ' ' . strftime('%c'))
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>c :call CompleteTasks()<CR>
```